# MongoClient - Works on one machine but not the other. How to Output Configuration/Version Information

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu-18.04

So I have two machines running in the cloud (both Ubuntu 18.04/Node 13/NPM 6.4) and on one machine I am running into issues with Mongo - I cannot figure out why.

Here is my simple script:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb';
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, async (err, client) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('Mongo Client: ', client)
    const db = client.db('mydb');
    console.log('Mongo DB Connected', db)
    const userCount = await db.collection('users').countDocuments()
    console.log('# of Users: ', userCount)
});
```

This works as expected on one machine, but on the other I get the following error:

```
(node:22716) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: db.collection(...).countDocuments is not a function
```

I am hoping there is a way to have MongoClient spit out it's configuration/version information in the script so that I can see some difference between the two??

Right now when the script runs and I log out "client" I see this on the working machine:

```
Mongo Client:  MongoClient {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] { newListener: [Function (anonymous)] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  s: {
    url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb',
    options: {
      servers: [Array],
      caseTranslate: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      checkServerIdentity: true,
      sslValidate: true,
      dbName: 'mydb',
      socketTimeoutMS: 0,
      connectTimeoutMS: 10000,
      retryWrites: true,
      useRecoveryToken: true,
      readPreference: [ReadPreference],
      promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise]
    },
    promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
    dbCache: Map {},
    sessions: Set {},
    writeConcern: undefined,
    readPreference: ReadPreference {
      mode: 'primary',
      tags: undefined,
      hedge: undefined
    },
    namespace: MongoDBNamespace { db: 'admin', collection: undefined }
  },
  topology: NativeTopology {
...
```

This is different than what I see on the non-working machine:

```
Mongo Client:  Db {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  s: {
    databaseName: 'mydb',
    dbCache: {},
    children: [],
    topology: Server {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      s: [Object],
      bson: [Getter],
      isMasterDoc: [Getter],
      poolSize: [Getter],
      autoReconnect: [Getter],
      host: [Getter],
      port: [Getter],
      emitOpen: false,
      connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
      socketTimeoutMS: 0
    },
    options: {
      read_preference_tags: null,
      readPreference: [ReadPreference],
      url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb',
      promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
      native_parser: true
    },
    logger: Logger { className: 'Db' },
    bson: BSON {},
    authSource: undefined,
    readPreference: ReadPreference {
      _type: 'ReadPreference',
      mode: 'primary',
      tags: undefined
    },
...
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might be a trivial question to ask, but is the collection of the same name created on the other server as well?

Comment: Thanks for the idea...yes the collection exists on both machines.

Answer (score 0):

When all else fails, reboot it. In my case I deleted Mongo and re-installed on the machine not working and now it works.

Comment: Closed the question.